# Activity has leaked

Tags: android, memory-leaks, progressdialog

I have an activity which is used to upload video to server. In this activity  ProgressDialog has been used to make it more intuitive. The error say that problem is in ProgressDialog. But when this activity is reached from different set of activity then file is getting uploaded and desired result is met but there is one Activity, which is producing this "Memory Leaked exception".

Note: I have ensured that video is paused like it is cited in another link of stackoverflow
I have ensure that all the dialogs are closed before new activity is opened.

My question is what may be the origin of such error, where it is working for some cases but not for other.

Comment: Can you post piece of code?

Comment: android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.gurung.dila.videoeditor.EarningVideoActivity has leaked

Comment: @DilaGurung show code

Comment: `LeakdWindow` is caused when there is dialog running and your activity gets destroyed, check for the errors that are causing activity to be crashed.

Comment: at com.gurung.dila.videoeditor.EarningVideoActivity$UploadV.onPreExecute(EarningVideoActivity.java:433)android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:587)
android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:535)
com.gurung.dila.videoeditor.EarningVideoActivity.onClick(EarningVideoActivity.java:209)

Comment: i think its because of progress dialog

Comment: @pRATIKPOPAT , yeah as the error says, the problem lies in progress dialog but its working if i change the origin(Activity One)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare your ProgressDialog as class variable.

```
public class DemoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    //....... 
}
```

Initialize it in onCreate Method.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_demo);

    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(DashboardWithDrw.this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    /........
}
```

and dismiss it in on `onPause()`

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    if(progressDialog!=null){
        progressDialog.cancel();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Main reason is object type that your code creates multiple times but
>   doesn’t destroy .Continually growing object trees that contain root or
>   dominator objects can prevent subordinate objects from being
>   garbage-collected. This issue is a common cause of memory leaks .

In your case, Make sure you **`dismiss()`** your **`DIALOG`** before Opening any Action .I guess your **`PROGRESS-DIALOG`** Running That's why problem coming.

> As you start narrowing down memory issues, you should also use the
>   **[Allocation Tracker](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/allocation-tracker-walkthru.html)** to get a better understanding of where your
>   memory-hogging objects are allocated .

Comment: To be specific, I have some video in activity A, which is trimmed, and once it  is trimmed , the video path and name is passed in another activity say Activity B which is used to upload supplied video to server. Its working in this case. But when the origin of video is say Activity C then memory is getting leaked, some times after it start uploading video.  I have ensure that all the pop up and progress dialog is closed before proceeding to new activity.. SHOULD I Call GARBAGE COLLECTOR TO GET REMEDY FOR THIS??

Comment: @DilaGurung `progress dialog is closed before proceeding to new activity` Please debug and make sure .

Comment: Yeah I have ensured it. I have ensure that everything is closed before proceeding to new activity

Comment: Initially I thought that is the source of error but that is not.

Comment: @DilaGurung oh..Didn't think about `onPause()` method . Move ahead .

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onDestroy(){
super.onDestroy();
if ( progressDialog!=null && progressDialog.isShowing() ){
    progressDialog.cancel();
}
}

public void onPause(){
super.onPause();
if ( progressDialog!=null && progressDialog.isShowing() ){
    progressDialog.cancel();
}
}
```